# How to disable sort in datatable when a specific button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have a add button in the datatable header where there is also a sort button. When I click on the add button it sorts the column and then opens a new page. I would like that when the add button is clicked that it opens a new page without sorting. How can I prevent this thank you for your help

Here is visual what it looks like

[image: The add button in header]

This is my html

```
<th><p><a id="open-new" class="btn" href="/fichaproveedor/AnadirEditar/0" ><i class="material-icons-add" title="Crear nuevo">add_box</i></a>Proveedor Id</p></th>
```

here is the complete generated html

```
<th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="proveedorTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 142px;" aria-label="add_boxProveedor Id: Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente" aria-sort="ascending"><p><a id="open-new" class="btn" href="/fichaproveedor/AnadirEditar/0"><i class="material-icons-add" title="Crear nuevo">add_box</i></a>Proveedor Id</p></th>
```

I believe that this problem is solvable whit javascript I have tried but failed to fix it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Will you include your controller code? Is the url parameter '0' in `/fichaproveedor/AnadirEditar/0` used to signal that it isn't sortable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this actually works, since I haven't tried this out myself and only based this is on what I read on the internet myself. but I hope it helps.

```
$( "#open-new" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

From what I understand, when you click on the icon, it should only perform the given action, so open the new page, and with `event.stopPropagation();` you'll stop any other events from happening.

If this actually stops the event but also stops it from opening a new page, try this:

```
$( "#open-new" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  window.open("/fichaproveedor/AnadirEditar/0");
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much your first solution worked for me.